# How to make such reference format? The quoted position in the paper is recorded in the reference

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing

The red mark records the position of the document in the paper

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this with `backref` option for the `biblatex`, along with `hyperref` for the links.

By default you'll get something like this:

[image]

You can change the appearance using `renewbibmacro`.
Here's a MWE that approximates your example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=BrickRed}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Dummy2015,
  title={A title},
  author={Dummy Author and Ann O Nymous},
  journal={Journal of Testing},
  volume={10},
  pages={1--7},
  year={2015}
}
@article{Nymous2032,
  title={Something},
  author={Ann O Nymous},
  journal={Fake Journal},
  volume={1},
  pages={1--9},
  year={2032}
}
@book{Dummy2002,
  title={Don't cite me on this},
  author={Dummy Author},
  year={2002}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% change pagereference format
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
   \iflistundef{pageref}%
     {}%
     {\printtext{\addperiod\space\(\uparrow\)%
      \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\begin{document}

% first page, make a reference
Cite one~\cite{Dummy2015} \newpage
% second page, make two references
Cite again~\cite{Nymous2032,Dummy2015} \newpage 
% inlcude one reference without citing it
\nocite{Dummy2002}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But, there is an error "Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package'backref' ". May I ask do you know the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm it worked for me, but try removing the `pagebackref` option to `hyperref`.  I think that is redundant, if you are passing the `backref` option to `biblatex`. Let me know.

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the `pagebackref` option.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works.

Comment: Ok. Of course. Thanks!